Discord bot is not playing given URL
I am working on a Discord music bot powered by discord-player v6.6.10 and discord.js v14.15.3.
Currently, when the user executes the /play command, the bot properly searches for the given URL, grabs the video, joins the channel, and then logs that it's starting playback.

Although after joining the channel, the bot is not transmitting any audio. It has administrator privileges and GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates so permissions aren't the issue here.
Here is my current play.js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { QueryType, useQueue } = require('discord-player');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('play')
        .setDescription('Plays a song from YouTube')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('url')
                .setDescription('The URL or name of the song')
                .setRequired(true)
        ),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const songQuery = interaction.options.getString('url');

        // Check if the user is in a voice channel
        const voiceChannel = interaction.member?.voice?.channel;
        if (!voiceChannel) {
            return interaction.reply({
                content: 'You need to be in a voice channel to play music!',
                ephemeral: true
            });
        }
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(interaction.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has("CONNECT") || !permissions.has("SPEAK")) {
            return interaction.reply({
                content: 'I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!',
                ephemeral: true
            });
        }
        await interaction.deferReply();

        const player = interaction.client.player;

        try {
            const result = await player.search(songQuery, {
                requestedBy: interaction.user,
                searchEngine: QueryType.AUTO
            });

            if (!result || !result.tracks.length) {
                return interaction.followUp('No results found for your query');
            }

            const track = result.tracks[0];
            console.log(`Track found: ${track.title}`);

            // Create the queue
            let queue = player.nodes.create(interaction.guild, {
                metadata: {
                    channel: interaction.channel,
                    interaction: interaction,
                },
                volume: 70,
                leaveOnEnd: false,
                leaveOnEmpty: true,
                leaveOnEmptyCooldown: 300000,
                bufferingTimeout: 3000
            });

            // Connect to the voice channel
            if (!queue.connection) await queue.connect(voiceChannel);

            // Add the track to the queue and play it
            queue.addTrack(track);
            console.log('Track added to queue.');

            if (!queue.node.isPlaying()) {
                console.log('Starting playback.');
                await queue.node.play();
            } else {
                console.log(`Track ${track.title} is already playing.`);
            }

            return interaction.followUp(`**${track.title}** enqueued!`);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error:', err);
            const queue = useQueue(interaction.guild.id);
            if (queue) queue.delete();
            return interaction.followUp(`An error occurred: ${err.message || err}`);
        }
    }
};

These are my logs:
Track found: [VRchat Worlds BGM] Spirits of the Sea 海の幽霊
Track added to queue.
Starting playback.

The bot does stay connected but if I set leaveOnEnd: to true the bot leaves as soon as it finishes the Starting playback. log.
